# Set up XML search engine for missing reference within one document?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

Have a very large xml file like this:

```
<root>
  <item id="1">
    <linkToItem>12345</linkToItem>
  </item>
  <item id="2">
    <linkToItem>234</linkToItem>
  </item>
  <!--lots more items -->
  <item id="12345"/>
</root>
```

How do I set up an engine for a simple search to find out if any of these elements, such as `<linktoItem>234</linkToItem>`, is missing its corresponding `<item>` id?

I would rather avoid setting up a program like oXygen editor with Saxon or other engine.

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution to this is to write a schema for your XML, and then validate the instance against the schema. Your schema should contain definitions of the various elements, and the element declaration for the root element should define the referential integrity constraint:

```
<xs:element name="root">
  ...
  <xs:key name="id-key">
    <xs:selector xpath="item"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
  </xs:key>
  <xs:keyref name="link" refer="id-key">
    <xs:selector xpath="item"/>
    <xs:field xpath="linkToItem"/>
  </xs:key>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this with XML Spear.

Answer (score 0):

Validating with an XML schema, like the one provided in Michael's answer, is the preferable option, but if a schema is not available or would take too long to develop, one could use a quick-n-dirty script like:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import xml.etree.ElementTree
import argparse
import os
import sys

root = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(sys.stdin)
parent_map = { c:p for p in root.iter() for c in p }

id_elements = root.findall('./item[@id]')
identifiers = set([ id_element.get('id') for id_element in id_elements ])

ref_elements = root.findall('./item/linkToItem')
for ref_element in (ref_elements):
    ref_id = ref_element.text
    if ref_id not in identifiers:
        print 'reference', ref_id, 'on item', parent_map[ref_element].get('id'), 'cannot be resolved'
```

Comment: Thanks @nerff! This was the kind of script I was looking for. I'll try it out.